# Работа с датой и временем

Tags: php, дата

По окончанию регистрации пользователю даётся 24 часа, чтобы активировать аккаунт, в противном случае он удаляется.

```
<?    
# Время регистрации пользователя в базе time()
$time '....';    

$date = $time + (24);    

echo date('Y-m-d', $date);    
?>
```

Допустим пользователь зарегистрировался сегодня 2017-07-05 значит +24 часа должно быть 2017-07-06, а в итоге получается текущая дата 2017-07-05

Вероятно, неправильно определено выражение в `$date`. Помогите исправить, пожалуйста.

Comment: `24 * 60 * 60` - количество секунд в 1 сутках.

Comment: @Visman ответ - в ответ)

Comment: В каком виде у вас сейчас $time и как вы его получаете?

Answer (score 1):

```
echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime('+1 day'));
```

Answer (score 1):

замени

```
$date = $time + (24);
```

на

```
$date = $time + (60*60*24);
```